# Differencing between model.addAttribute("name",value) and mv.addObject("name",value)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What differencing between

`model.addAttribute("name",value)`

and

`mv.addObject("name",value)` in spring-mvc?

model is Model

mv is ModelAndView

Comment: Are these classes found within the standard Java API? If not, perhaps you should specify the classes' origin.

Comment: @Josh `Model` is an interface provided by spring-mvc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Model#addAttribute(String, Object)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html#addAttribute%28java.lang.Object%29) states

> Add the supplied attribute under the supplied name.

while [`ModelAndView#addObject(String, Object)`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/ModelAndView.html#addObject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) states

> Add an attribute to the model.

If you look at the source code for `addObject`

```
public ModelAndView addObject(String attributeName, Object attributeValue) {
    getModelMap().addAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue);
    return this;
}
```

it's delegating to the `Model` reference that a `ModelAndView` holds and calling `addAttribute()` on it.

Comment: So they pretty much do the same thing, right? Except for the return statement

Comment: @KevinBowersox Not completely. The two classes serve different purposes, but the end result is the same: a model object with the name provided is added to the model.

Comment: That's kinda where I was heading the end result is the same. Interesting I never knew those methods returned the model or mav so they can be chained.

Answer (score 3):

[Model](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html)  is a holder for model attributes only.

[ModelAndView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html) is a holder for both Model and View , so that the controller can return both model and view together.